# When connecting diagnostic PC to OBD port - What is the most detailed output file?

Tags: diagnostics, obd

When the garage connecting the "official" manufacturer software to the OBD port in the car - What is the most detailed file that can be retrieved, containing all the raw data information?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't make a lot of sense. All manufacturer specific software work in different ways. They can provide files with raw output but that is not the default thing to do. Normally you read data from the correct bus for the vehicle and then display it in the software or on a handheld device. For more information regarding how OBD works, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics